# how to redirect from website.com/index to website.com

Tags: htaccess, redirection

For example, visitor types `www.website.com/index`. I want to remove `index` and show this url `www.website.com`

In `.htaccess` wrote

`RedirectMatch 301 /index https://www.website.com`

As result instead of `https://www.website.com` get `https:///www.website.com/?index` with 404 error.

Please advice what is the correct way to redirect.

**Some solution.**

Did it not in `.htaccess`, but in php file.

This works

```
if( trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '/index' ){ 
header('Location: https://www.domain.com', true, 301 );
exit();
}
```

but may be some better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can find all you need in the [ExpressionEngine documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html) which discusses this issue and provides some sample code.